# Is there a way to pad openCV matricies in c++ to be a certain size?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am currently working on an algorithm which breaks down matricies into squares of 10x10 and checks whether or not there is a certain colour in it.

For now the background is black and the error it is looking for is anything other than that.

The problem that I am faced with is that not all matrices that are analysed have dimesnions that are divisible by a factor of 10.

Is it possible to extend my openCV matrices to be a factor of 10?

So for example if I have:

CurrentImage = cv::Mat::zeros(98, 78, CV_8UC1);

Could it be patched to be have thedimensions rounded up to 100x80 where the extension pixels are also black?

Comment: 1) create a bigger mat with the rounded size, and copy the small one into the big one, or 2) use copyMakeBorder to fill the gap